# Android Setting Up Splash Screen(Activity) Like Iphone Part2

Tags: java, android, xml, scroll

After getting solution to call my splash activity only one time ([Part1 Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163365/android-setting-up-splash-screenactivity-like-iphone-part1)), Now i have to set up my splash activity.

On My First Layout i want functionality like this :

**Image One <-->  Image Two  <--> Imgage Three --> Second xml(Activity)**

**Also on every image their will be a page control that will indicate on which image is currently on layout(Like the attached screenshot)/ or can be any other way to show this.**

That Means From Image one i can go to image two on scrolling to right(I can come back to image one on scrolling to left) From Image two i can go to Image Three on scrolling right(I can come back to image 2 from Image three if i scroll to left)But if i scroll to right from Third Image then i should get to my Second Activity and never return back on those images.

i.e
I want to have scroll view having those three images with the page controller then after we scroll down to the third/last image on further scrolling to right i want that my second activity should be loaded and the splash should never come up.

Can any one tell me any idea how this can be done.

To make splash sheet with scroll view and page control & switch to second activity when done scrolling.
I don't want animation i want it to work manually like scrolling/ or any other way to implement this.

Coding will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It would help to know where exactly you see any difficulties, because I see this as relatively trivial. And no, we don't do your coding here. (Or maybe someone will, but you can't count on it.)

Comment: @ClassStacker i never asked for the whole code if you can read above i clearly asked if any one knows any code or any method to implement this functionality, it will save some time if i get some code but i just want some good idea to get this functionality working. The Exact Difficulty is my approach i don't know how to do it in android.

Comment: "i never asked for the whole code if you can read above i clearly asked if any one knows any code" -> must be a misunderstanding due to the language barrier I guess, because you clearly wrote "Coding will be much appreciated." "Coding" is an activity, whereas "links to code snippets" would be something completely different.

Comment: @ClassStacker you don't get it i told you not the Whole code, but it can save my time if i get some code.... If you have any answers to my question then you are most welcome otherwise no need of your comments, I am not in a mood for a fight.

Comment: When I take the time to clarify a misunderstanding and give you feedback about your language (which comes across pretty arrogant), I don't appreciate being told that I "don't get it". Besides, it is more than obvious that you want to save as much time as you can, so it's really very hard to "not get that". And regardless of what kind of comments _you_ welcome, it's still 2 upvotes for my comment and 1 for yours, and we're on StackOverflow, where certain rules apply. So good luck, my dear friend.

Comment: @ClassStacker hummm i see .... Good Luck to you too 2/1 vote look's like you are worried ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To implement scrollable images like shown above use `ViewPagerIndicator` library given [HERE](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). Its simple to integrate and will take few minutes. All you have to do is read the *usage* section in given link.
2. For switching activity on last page, simply implement `onPageChangeListener` described in link and check for page number.

Comment: Thx dude ... This will help me alot !!